# Reordering different types of arrays with correspondence

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have this:

```
string[] old = new string[] {"a","b","c","d"};
```

that represents the values of a 2D array columns :

```
double[,] values = new double[,] {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{1,3,5,9}};
```

how to use linq to reoder the columns of this 2D array reordering the string array values as

```
string[] newer = new string[] {"c","a","d","b"};
```

I am using an auxiliary int array to keep new indexes but I would like to use LINQ! :)

```
        int[] aux = new int[old.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < newer.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < old.Length; j++)
            {
                if (old[j] == newer[i])
                {
                    aux[i] = j;
                }
            }
        }

        double[,] newvalues = new double[values.GetLength(0), values.GetLength(1)];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < values.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                newvalues[i, j] = values[i, aux[j]];
            }
        }

        values = newvalues;
```

Comment: Must it be on a rectangular `[,]` array or can it be on a jagged `[][]` array?

Comment: rectangular, I fixed the code... `newvalues[i, j] = values[i, aux[j]];`

Comment: It's fine, converting between the two is easy enough.

Comment: Hmmm. Try to get your question right before people waste time trying to help you solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do this for jagged arrays, since it's easier, and going back and forth between the two is a [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010219/jagged-arrays-multidimensional-arrays-conversion-in-asp-net) problem.

The punchline is this, it's very simple:

```
Array.Sort(keys, doubles, new CustomStringComparer(reorderedKeys));
```

Here's the setup to get that working:

```
var doubles = 
    new double[][] {
        new double[] {1, 2, 3, 4},
        new double[] {5, 6, 7, 8},
        new double[] {1, 3, 5, 7},
        new double[] {2, 4, 6, 8}
    };
var keys = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var reorderedKeys = new [] { "c", "a", "d", "b" };
```

Here, I use:

```
 class CustomStringComparer : IComparer<string> {
    Dictionary<string, int> ranks;

    public CustomStringComparator(string[] reorderedKeys) {
        ranks = reorderedKeys
            .Select((value, rank) => new { Value = value, Rank = rank })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Rank);
    }

    public int Compare(string x, string y) {
        return ranks[x].CompareTo(ranks[y]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multidimensional arrays with Linq because they don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. If instead you choose to use jagged arrays:

```
double[][] values = new double[][] {
    new double[]{1,2,3,4},
    new double[]{5,6,7,8}, 
    new double[]{1,3,5,9}};
//...    
newer
    .Join(
        old.Zip(values, (key, val) => new{key, val}), 
        a => a, 
        b => b.key, 
        (a, b) => b.val)
    .ToArray()
```

Comment: This does not work due to dimensions mismatch... You (same as mine answer) assume 4*3 `values` array, while it is 3*4 and first dimension (3) does not match length of `old`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Evil original poster changed their question. Original revisions had 4*3