# How to convert between 2d array and jagged array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Whats the easiest/ most canonical way to convert from a multidimensional array into an array of arrays and vice versa?

For example, what is an elegant way to convert the following array of arrays `int[][]`

```
int[][] arrayArray = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2 },
    new int[] { 3, 4 },
    new int[] { 5, 6 },
    new int[] { 7, 8 }
};
```

Into an multidimensional `int[,]` which looks like:

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { 
    { 1, 2 }, 
    { 3, 4 }, 
    { 5, 6 }, 
    { 7, 8 }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Keith and the other way?

Comment: Since the data is stored in memory differently for each, there is no super efficient approach, it just comes down to loops or if you want to get fancy linq

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986909/convert-multidimensional-array-to-jagged-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: I'm very surprised to see that this operation isn't as easy as one or two lines. Even when we assume that the data is a square matrix is it still as complicated?